# Why is Crowd HTML breaking this image?

Tags: javascript, amazon-sagemaker, mechanicalturk

I'm using Crowd HTML Elements to perform bounding box annotation, but when I attempt to load some of my images, I get this error in the dev tools console:

```
crowd-html-elements.js:1 window.onError received an event without an error:  {event: ErrorEvent}
(anonymous) @ crowd-html-elements.js:1
error (async)
e @ crowd-html-elements.js:1
e @ crowd-html-elements.js:1
./src/crowd-html-elements-loader.ts @ crowd-html-elements.js:1
s @ crowd-html-elements.js:1
(anonymous) @ crowd-html-elements.js:1
(anonymous) @ crowd-html-elements.js:1
crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282 window.onError received an event without an error:  {event: ErrorEvent}
(anonymous) @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282
error (async)
e @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282
e @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282
./src/index.ts @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282
r @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:1
(anonymous) @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:1
(anonymous) @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:1
crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282 Uncaught Error: Unexpected image dimensions during normalization
    at Function.normalizeHeight (crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282)
    at Function.normalizeDimensions (crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282)
    at new a (crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282)
    at ie.handleTargetImageLoaded (crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282)
    at Image.r.onload (crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282)
normalizeHeight @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282
normalizeDimensions @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282
a @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282
handleTargetImageLoaded @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282
r.onload @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282
load (async)
setBackgroundImage @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282
renderImageSrcChange @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282
shouldComponentUpdate @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282
q @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
B @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
q @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
B @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
F @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
N @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
E @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
N @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
E @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
N @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
E @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
N @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
T @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
q @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
B @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
F @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
N @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
T @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
G @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
w @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
S @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
e.reactMount @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:3
e.updateRegion @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:3
(anonymous) @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:3
(anonymous) @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:3
(anonymous) @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:3
e.reactBatchUpdate @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:3
i @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:3
f.componentDidUpdate @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:3
q @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
B @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
F @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
N @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
E @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
N @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
E @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
N @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
T @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
q @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
B @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
q @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
B @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
q @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
B @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
q @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
B @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
F @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
N @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
E @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
N @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
T @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
G @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
w @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6278
_renderReactComponent @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282
_updateReactComponent @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:6282
Y @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:5984
C @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:5984
k @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:5984
_propertiesChanged @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:5984
_flushProperties @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:5954
_flushProperties @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:5984
_invalidateProperties @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:5984
_setProperty @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:5984
Object.defineProperty.set @ crowd-html-elements-without-ce-polyfill.js:5954
(anonymous) @ labeling.html:199
async function (async)
(anonymous) @ labeling.html:198
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ labeling.html:196
```

The **Unexpected image dimensions during normalization** portion seems like the issue, but I've found nothing with regard to troubleshooting.  Can someone explain what expected image dimensions are and why some are failing?

Here's a snippet of the code that's throwing the error.

```
            static normalizeHeight(e) {
                if (e.height === e.naturalHeight)
                    return e.height;
                if (e.height === e.naturalWidth)
                    return e.height;
                if (Math.abs(e.height - e.naturalHeight) < 2)
                    return e.naturalHeight;
                if (Math.abs(e.height - e.naturalWidth) < 2)
                    return e.naturalWidth;
                throw new Error("Unexpected image dimensions during normalization")
            }
            static normalizeWidth(e) {
                if (e.width === e.naturalWidth)
                    return e.width;
                if (e.width === e.naturalHeight)
                    return e.width;
                if (Math.abs(e.width - e.naturalWidth) < 2)
                    return e.naturalWidth;
                if (Math.abs(e.width - e.naturalHeight) < 2)
                    return e.naturalHeight;
                throw new Error("Unexpected image dimensions during normalization")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi AppleBaggins, thanks for raising this question. Is it possible for you to share the following: The image, or if not the image itself then the file extension and dimensions? What browser you're using? Is your browser zoomed in or out?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.  I can share the image with you via DM or email, if that's possible.  It's a simple JPEG with average dimensions in a standard aspect ratio.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Chrome and am not zooming in or out.
One image is a JPG file and dimensions are 2256 x 1496.

Comment: Hi, please share the image, upload it to google drive, make it public and share the link here.

Comment: Along with that share the crowd HTML tag code.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not allowed to share the images publicly.
```
<crowd-form id="myCrowd">
  <crowd-bounding-box
    name="annotatedResult"
    labels="[ -all my labels are in this list- ]"
    src={{ variable for template engine }}
    header="Select a label and draw boxes around stuff."
    id="annotator"
  >
Instruction code is in here...
  </crowd-bounding-box>
</crowd-form>
```
I've determined that my CSS style sheet is conflicting with the layout.  I'll troubleshoot to find out exactly how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be related to the css styling that was being applied to the canvas portion of my site that was loading the labeling tools.